# div colour change jquery on a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms, telerik

A complete button is there . I have some Toggle buttons that are placed in a table . This toggle button can have no value, Yes / No or NA values. When the complete button is clicked, i like to change the colour of toggle button or atleast  the div.  I have following code . When i check in the Developer console and run the commands,  it is changing the div colour, but not when running it(not updating from console) .

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on('click', '#btnComplete', function() {

    if ($('#btnToggleIntro1').val().trim().length < 1) {
      $('#divIntro').attr('style', 'background-color: blue');
      //css('background-color', 'blue');
      //  $('#btnToggleIntro1').css('background-color', '#A497E5');
    } else {
      $('#btnToggleIntro1').css('background-color', '#ffffff');
    }


  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divIntro">
  <telerik:RadToggleButton ID="btnToggleIntro1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False" Font-Size="14px" meta:resourcekey="btnToggle11Resource1" class="RecomenderButton" ClientIDMode="Static">
    <ToggleStates>
      <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text=" " meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource1" />
      <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="Yes" meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource2" />
      <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="No" meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource3" />
      <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="N/A" />

    </ToggleStates>
  </telerik:RadToggleButton>
</div>
```

Following is the rendered sample fo the table where i want the colour to be changed

```
  <div id="divIntroduction">
                                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped" id="tbIntroduction">

                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="light-blue-background text-center" colspan="4">INTRODUCTION </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="text-left">
                                        <td class="text-center col-xs-1"></td>
                                        <td class="col-xs-5 ">Is this a Staff or instruction.
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="text-center col-xs-2" style="vertical-align: middle">
                                            <div id="divIntro">
                                                <button type="submit" name="btnToggleIntro1" value="Yes" id="btnToggleIntro1" class="RadToggleButton RadButton RadButton_Bootstrap rbButton rbRounded rbIconButton" class="RecomenderButton" style="font-size:14px;"><span class="rbText">Yes</span><input id="btnToggleIntro1_ClientState" name="btnToggleIntro1_ClientState" type="hidden" /></button>
                                            </div>

                                        </td>
                                        <td class="text-center col-xs-2" style="vertical-align: middle">
                                            <button type="submit" name="btnToggleIntroAprv" value=" " id="btnToggleIntroAprv" class="RadToggleButton RadButton RadButton_Bootstrap rbButton rbRounded rbIconButton" style="font-size:14px;"><span class="rbText"> </span><input id="btnToggleIntroAprv_ClientState" name="btnToggleIntroAprv_ClientState" type="hidden" /></button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not from the aspx page"?

Comment: @Dekel, while i run the page and button is clicked in the ASPX page.

Comment: button is clicked in the browser, so i'm not sure I understand what you mean by "button is clicked in the ASPX page".

Comment: The browser only knows html, javascript and css and doesn't know or care how it is generated server side. Provide a rendered html sample that reproduces your issue

Comment: it's 2018, please do `$('#btnComplete').click( function( ...` and `$('#divIntro').prop(...`

Comment: also you can just do `if ($('#btnToggleIntro1').val()){ }` to determine if a button has text

Comment: I want to avoid  space "  " also,  thats why did the trim @HanjunChen

Comment: @makdu it detects empty string and `"                             "`. I tried it on the stackoverflow website. Just put a bunch of spaces in the search box and do `console.log($('input.js-search-field').val()==false)`

Comment: and also do you have to use Telerik?

Comment: Yes. The front end used Telerik

Comment: @HanjunChen absolutely nothing wrong with `$(document).on('click',selector..` for event delgation

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest solution is to use css  and on button click for toggle button, change the colour

```css
<style type="text/css">.Checked {
  background-color: white !important;
}

.notChecked {
  background-color: indianred !important;
}

</style>
```

```html
<div id="divIntro">
  <telerik:RadToggleButton ID="btnToggleIntro1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False" Font-Size="14px">
    <ToggleStates>
      <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text=" " meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource1" CssClass="notChecked" />
      <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="Yes" meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource2" CssClass="Checked" />
      <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="No" meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource3" CssClass="Checked" />
      <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="N/A" CssClass="Checked" />

    </ToggleStates>
  </telerik:RadToggleButton>
</div>
```